# Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault in getter method

Tags: c++, sdl

I was making a game using Code::Blocks, and came across the Segmentation fault error. I have looked through other questions here and couldn't find anything that helped. I have a `Sprite` class that represents the basic objects in the game and a `Window` class that controls the display to the screen of the game. I ran the debugger and it gave me the error at the line `return image;` from the `getImage()` method below.

```
SDL_Surface* Sprite::getImage() {
    return image;
}
```

I call the following `setImage()` method in the constructor for `Sprite`, and I verified that `SDL_ConvertSurface` did not return `NULL`.

```
void Sprite::setImage(string path) {
    SDL_Surface* loadedSurface = IMG_Load( path.c_str() );
    if( loadedSurface == NULL ) {
        printf( "Unable to load image %s! SDL_image Error: %s\n", path.c_str(), IMG_GetError() );
    } else {
        image = SDL_ConvertSurface( loadedSurface, surface->format, NULL );
        if( image == NULL ) {
            printf( "Unable to optimize image %s! SDL Error: %s\n", path.c_str(), SDL_GetError() );
        }

        SDL_FreeSurface( loadedSurface );
    }
}
```

I call the method `getImage()` in `mainloop()` of `Window`, as shown below, where `sprites` is declared as `Sprite* sprites[10];`:

```
void Window::mainloop() {
    bool quit = false;
    SDL_Event e;

    while( !quit ) {
        while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0 ) {
            if( e.type == SDL_QUIT ) {
                quit = true;
            }
        }

        SDL_FillRect( screenSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB( screenSurface->format, red, green, blue ) );

        for (int i = 0; i < spritesNum; i++) {
            SDL_BlitScaled( sprites[spritesNum]->getImage() , NULL, screenSurface, sprites[spritesNum]->getRect() );
        }

        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( window );
    }
}
```

Comment: have you run it in a debugger?  It should stop at the seg fault.  Mostly likely you have a null pointer or are calling a method on a nonexistent object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably indexing out of range here

```
for (int i = 0; i < spritesNum; i++) {
    SDL_BlitScaled( sprites[spritesNum]->getImage() , NULL, screenSurface, sprites[spritesNum]->getRect() );
}
```

I assume you wanted to use your counter `i`?

```
for (int i = 0; i < spritesNum; i++) {
    SDL_BlitScaled( sprites[i]->getImage() , NULL, screenSurface, sprites[i]->getRect() );
}
```

Otherwise if your array `sprites` is of length `spritesNum` you are indexing out of range, and doing so `spritesNum` number of times.

In any case, you should at least confirm you aren't dereferencing a null pointer here

```
sprites[i]->getImage()
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I missed that.